# Gravity Forms - Drop Down based of entries from Database

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to `WordPress` and I work with the plugin `Gravityforms`.

I would like to know how to retrieve the data from a table in my database in a `Dropdown`, so that when I open my page there is a `Dropdown` field whose data comes from my database.

If anyone has an idea of how I can go about it, or write the code etc. It would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. This site is not a code writing service, and we expect you to do a reasonable amount of research yourself before you ask. // Their official documentation already has an example for how such a thing works, https://docs.gravityforms.com/dynamically-populating-drop-down-fields/

Answer (score 0):

Gravity Forms has a great example of how to populate Drop Down fields dynamically via hooks in the link below. In your case, you would need to fetch your entries via the `GFAPI::get_entries()` method rather than WordPress' `get_posts()` function.

https://docs.gravityforms.com/dynamically-populating-drop-down-fields/

If you don't feel comfortable customizing the code examples, Gravity Forms Populate Anything provides point-and-click UI for populating any choice-based fields (including Drop Downs) and support for filtering which entries get populated.

https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-populate-anything/